# Regex: Match up to, but not including word, and still match if word does not exist

Tags: python, regex

I have files in the following format:

```
123_example-1234567_any-characters_here!-ignore.ext
```

And I want to capture the four groups:

1. `123_example`
2. `1234567`
3. `any-characters_here!`
4. `.ext`

Which I can do just fine with something like

```
^(\d{3}_[^\-]+)-(\d+)_(.+)-ignore(\.ext)$
```

However, sometimes these files do not have the `-ignore` string (assume this string can only ever be `-ignore`). For example:

```
123_example-1234567_any-characters_here!.ext
```

How can I modify my regex so that it matches both strings and returns the same groups?

My attempt on https://regex101.com/r/pOnEIe/1 where I thought a capture group inside a non capture group might have been the answer.

Comment: In your own regex, just change `-ignore` to `(-ignore)?` [Check your updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/pOnEIe/2)

Comment: Unfortunately that still leaves `-ignore` in the 4th capture group.

Comment: To maintain group numbers, you can ungroup using `?:` just before the starting bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The capture group at the end should contain a non greedy quantifier, and following that should be the optional group for `-ignore`

Note that this part `[^-]+` might als match newlines.

```
^(\d{3}_[^-]+)-(\d+)_(.+?)(?:-ignore)?(\.ext)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(\d{3}_[^-]+)` Capture 3 digits, match `_` and 1+ chars other than `-`
- `-(\d+)_` Match `-`, capture 1+ digits and match `_`
- `(.+?)` Capture 1+ chars, as few as possible
- `(?:-ignore)?` Optionally match `-ignore`
- `(\.ext)` Capure `.ext`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EByFh1/1)